# validating white space,empty space and integer

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

How to validate white space,empty space and integer in a single method.Consider my forms.py

```
class UserprofileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Userprofile
        fields=['username1','phonenumber1','username1','phonenumber1']
```

How to validate this.

- All the fields are not mandatory.
- But if username1 or username2 is entered and not entered phonenumber1 or phonenumber2 respectively ,it should raise validation error.
- If any white space is entered,it should also raise validation error.
- Is any way to use strip() in views.py to validate whitespace.

Can anyone tell how to achieve  this.Please give me an example to how to perform.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything that didn't work? Asking people to do your work for you isn't in the sprit of StackOverflow.

Comment: I am learning django,i googled and got some link for validation about all the above but i don't know how to apply all in a single method.Writing separate clean_field() method for each field will take more than 35 lines.What i am expecting is all should happen in a single clean() method.So the code will be look very nice.I am just expecting the help from you experts.

Comment: Both answer seems correct except for white space validation,so how to validate for white space in same method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use clean() method to do your validation logic in it:

```
class UserprofileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Userprofile
        fields=['username1','phonenumber1','username1','phonenumber1']

    def clean(self):
        # do your validation here, such as
        cleaned_data = super(UserprofileForm, self).clean()
        username1 = cleaned_data.get("username1")
        username2 = cleaned_data.get("username2")
        phonenumber1 = cleaned_data.get("phonenumber1")
        phonenumber2 = cleaned_data.get("phonenumber2")
        if (
            ((username1 and not username1.isspace()) and not phonenumber1) or
            ((username2 and not username2.isspace()) and not phonenumber2) or
            ((not username1 or username1.isspace()) and phonenumber1 is not None) or
            ((not username2 or username2.isspace()) and phonenumber2 is not None)
        ):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Name and phone number required.")
        return cleaned_data
```

You can refer to the Django Doc:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

Comment: How to validate for white space,is it possible in this same method with this logic

Comment: You can use (username1 and username1.isspace()) to validate white space.

Comment: crossin,i followed your answer,sorry to say the validation is not happening.I tried with some code in that i don't have idea how to implement for white space soCan you please provide me how to validate white space if i update my tried code.

Comment: if ((usernam1 and not username1.isspace()) and not (phonenumber1 and not phonenumber1.isspace())) or ((usernam2 and not username2.isspace()) and not (phonenumber2 and not phonenumber2.isspace())):    raise forms.ValidationError

Comment: I tried this Getting this error "'int' object has no attribute 'isspace'"

Comment: so your phonenumber is int. Form validation will check white space for you. cleaned_data.get("phonenumber1") will return None if get white space. so,  if ((usernam1 and not username1.isspace()) and not phonenumber1) or ((usernam2 and not username2.isspace()) and not phonenumber2)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30464/discussion-between-user2161650-and-crossin)

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserprofileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Userprofile
        fields=['username1','phonenumber1','username2','phonenumber2']

    def clean(self):
        if 'username1' in self.cleaned_data and 'phonenumber1' in self.cleaned_data:
            if not (self.cleaned_data['username1'] and self.cleaned_data['phonenumber1']):
                raise forms.ValidationError("You must enter both username1 and phonenumber1")
        if 'username2' in self.cleaned_data and 'phonenumber2' in self.cleaned_data:
            if not (self.cleaned_data['username2'] and self.cleaned_data['phonenumber2']):
                raise forms.ValidationError("You must enter both username2 and phonenumber2")


        return self.cleaned_data
```

you can check this validation method. thnaks